# How I can fix this : Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider: Provider org.slf4j.log4j12.Log4j12ServiceProvider could not be instantiated

Comment: Could you add a link to the code or post some of the code with your question?  This link shows some guidelines on providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)